# Trouble targeting a certain HTML tag with Python, requests, and BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing an app in Python using requests and BeautifulSoup and have encountered a problem finding the text of a specific  element.

Essentially you enter a zip code and it requests a Bing search (Bing has easier to use search query URLs than Google) for "[zip code] weather". I'm able to pull the temperature, day, location, etc., but when targeting the 10-day forecast I ran into a problem. I've included the code and the HTML below:

**Python Code:**

## 10-Day Forecast

```
    forecast = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_innerScroll"})
    for link in forecast:
        day_tabs = link.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_forecastDay wtr_noselect"})
        for day in day_tabs:
            weekday = day.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_weekday"}).text
            temp_high = day.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_high"})
            temp_low = day.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_low"})
            precip = day.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_daypreci"})

            print(weekday.text + "\n" + "High: " + temp_high.text + " " + "Low: " + temp_low.text + "\n" + precip.text)
```

I'm having trouble formatting the HTML, but here's a screenshot:

[HTML Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFfvO.png)

For each day of the 10-day forecast, you have a wtr-weekday, wtr-high, wtr-low, and wtr-precip class(I'm ignoring the image element). These elements contain the text information I'm hoping to print to the console to complete my program. I'd prefer to loop over each element since they have indexed numbers in the HTML, but am lost as to how to exactly do that, as well as if I'm even targeting the elements correctly...

Also, here's the URL I'm using: https://www.bing.com/search?q=60657+weather

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like those `div` elements are dynamically generated.  The actual HTML that `requests.get()` pulls down a bunch of Javascript that is used to make the HTML.  Requests and BeautifulSoup can't get at dynamically generated HTML on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are targeting everything correctly.  The couple errors in your code are that you are using `find_all` for you `day in day_tabs` elements when you should be using just `find`.

Another small error is that you are converting your `weekday` variable to a string by appending the `.text` to the end of the `find_all` function and then you are trying to call `.text` on it in the `print` function.  You need to drop one or the other.

With those small corrections, you should be achieving the results you are looking for.  All together it's

```
page = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search?q=60657+weather")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

forecast = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_innerScroll"})
for link in forecast:
    day_tabs = link.find_all("div", {"class": "wtr_forecastDay wtr_noselect"})
    for day in day_tabs:
        weekday = day.find("div", {"class": "wtr_weekday"})
        temp_high = day.find("div", {"class": "wtr_high"})
        temp_low = day.find("div", {"class": "wtr_low"})
        precip = day.find("div", {"class": "wtr_daypreci"})

        print(weekday.text, "\nHigh:", temp_high.text, "Low:", temp_low.text + "\n" + precip.text)
```

Comment: Hey thanks @jk622 !!! This worked perfectly. I think I just messed up with the .text calls in the print statement. Thank you for your help!